# Move Array between loops

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Okay, so are part of my project, ive hit a stump. I need to be able to select a category and then have it point to a list of words, which are then needed for various uses.

SO far ive split up my words into the the various category and they are able to be embedded into my 2D array. However, i now need a was to check those words against a user input to see if they match.

Ive made a function that checks the 2 array for a match, however am having trouble getting the word to input in the function.

Here is how my words are sorted.

```
        printf("\n\n------------------------------");
        printf("\n1. Animals");
        printf("\n2. Colors");
        printf("\n3. Planets");
        printf("\n4. Weekdays");
        printf("\n------------------------------");


        int valid = 0;
        while(valid == 0)
        {
                    printf("\n\nYour selection: ");
                    int catagory;
                    scanf("%d", &catagory);

                    if(catagory == 1)
                    {
                                char word[] = "dog";
                                char word2[] = "cat";
                                char word3[] = "chicken";
                                char word4[] = "mouse";
                                char word5[] = "lion";
                                char word6[] = "rabbit";
                                char word7[] = "pig";                                  
                                horizontal(myArray, word);
                                horizontal(myArray, word2);
                                diagonal(myArray, word3);
                                diagonal(myArray, word4);
                                vertical(myArray, word5);
                                vertical(myArray, word6);
                                horizontal(myArray, word7);  
                                valid++;


                    }
                    else if(catagory == 2)
                    {
                                char word[] = "red";
                                char word2[] = "blue";
                                char word3[] = "yellow";
                                char word4[] = "brown";
                                char word5[] = "pink";
                                char word6[] = "green";
                                char word7[] = "black";
                                horizontal(myArray, word);
                                horizontal(myArray, word2);
                                diagonal(myArray, word3);
                                diagonal(myArray, word4);
                                vertical(myArray, word5);
                                vertical(myArray, word6);
                                horizontal(myArray, word7);  
                                valid++;

                    }
                    else if(catagory == 3)
                    {
                                char word[] = "earth";
                                char word2[] = "neptune";
                                char word3[] = "venus";
                                char word4[] = "mars";
                                char word5[] = "jupiter";
                                char word6[] = "saturn";
                                char word7[] = "pluto";
                                horizontal(myArray, word);
                                horizontal(myArray, word2);
                                diagonal(myArray, word3);
                                diagonal(myArray, word4);
                                vertical(myArray, word5);
                                vertical(myArray, word6);
                                horizontal(myArray, word7); 
                                valid++;

                    }
                    else if(catagory == 4)
                    {
                                char word[] = "monday";
                                char word2[] = "tuesday";
                                char word3[] = "wednesday";
                                char word4[] = "thursday";
                                char word5[] = "friday";
                                char word6[] = "saturday";
                                char word7[] = "saturn";
                                horizontal(myArray, word);
                                horizontal(myArray, word2);
                                diagonal(myArray, word3);
                                diagonal(myArray, word4);
                                vertical(myArray, word5);
                                vertical(myArray, word6);
                                horizontal(myArray, word7);  
                                valid++;

                    }
                    else if(catagory > 4)
                    {
                                printf("\n\nInvalid input. Please select again.\n");                                    
                    }
                    else if(catagory < 1)
                    {
                                printf("\n\nInvalid input. Please select again.\n");
                    }
        }
```

Below this i now need those words again:

```
        clock_t start = clock(), diff;
        int match = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        print_array(myArray);
        printf("\nPlease type any words that you can find");
        while (correct != 7)
        {                 
              printf("\n: ");
              char word2[256];
              fgets(word2,256,stdin);

              match = checker("word from category",word2);
              if(match == 1)
              {
                  correct++;
                  printf("\nWeldone you found a match!");
              }

        }


        diff = clock() - start;

        int msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000,                       msec%1000);
```

As you can see, my arrays are out of scope. Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe defining a global three-dimensional array could help here:

```
char words[4][8][];

words[0] = {"dog", "cat", "chicken", "mouse", "lion", "rabbit", "pig"};
//etc...

(you can of course define it in one line)
```

and then you can just access it using:

```
words[catagory][<WORD>]
```

(the last dimension is for the word itself)

Or did I misanderstand your question? I'd then need to know what your `horizontal` `vertical` and `diagonal` functions are doing and well, the whole code.

Comment: Those functions are embedding the words into a big 20x20 array. Will post example of horizontal code now

Answer (score 0):

```
    int horizontal(char *myArray, char * word)
    {
         int success = 0;
         while(success == 0)
         {
              int lettercount = 0;
              int length = strlen(word);
              int rand = rand_num_gen();
              //printf("i = %d\n", rand);
              int a;     
              for(a=0; a < (length); a++)
              {
                  if(myArray[rand] == '.')
                  {
                       myArray[rand] = word[a];
                       rand++; 
                       lettercount++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      break;
                  }
              }
              //printf("lettercount = %d\n", lettercount);
              //printf("length = %d\n", length);
              if(lettercount == length)
              {
                  success = 1;      
              }
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand, your first snippet is to take user input and decide which set of words to use.

A good practice is to separate concerns, so you should separate your data from the choosing, then call a function to place all your words on the 2 dimensional array (I'm guessing this is a word search?).

```
void letsPlayAGame() {
  char categories[4][8][20] ={
    {"dog", "cat", "chicken", "mouse", "lion", "rabbit", "pig"},
    {"red", "blue", "yellow", "brown", "pink", "green", "black"},
    {"earth", "neptune", "venus", "mars", "jupiter", 
      "saturn", "pluto"},
    {"monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday",
      "saturday", "saturn"}
  };

  int category = getCategory();

  //place words onto an array
  //assuming board size is 10x10
  char[10][10] myArray;
  placeWords(myArray, categories[category]);

  queryResponce(myArray, categories[category]);
}
int getCategory(){
  int cagetory = -1;
  while(category == -1){
    //ask for category
  }
  return category;
}
char** placeWords(char** myArray, char** category){
  //add your words to it with diagonal, etc
  //return your array
}
void queryResponse(char** myArray, char** answers){
    clock_t start = clock(), diff;
    int match = 0;
    int correct = 0;
    print_array(myArray);
    printf("\nPlease type any words that you can find");
    while (correct != 7)
    {                 
          printf("\n: ");
          char word[256];
          fgets(word,256,stdin);

          //check if word is in answers
          match = word_in(word,answers);
          if(match == 1)
          {
              correct++;
              printf("\nWeldone you found a match!");
          }

    }


    diff = clock() - start;

    int msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000,                       msec%1000);
}
```